# Pascal's identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can prove the first two equation using algebra but can someone tell me how we get the second equation in the first place. Do we somehow manipulate the first to get it?
I am talking about this [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)
 I am confused because pascal's identity is written in a number of ways

Comment: A heads-up: your link terminated at "Pascal's," so I edited it so that it covered "Pascal's_rule" because the former just linked to a disambiguation page.  If it's wrong, just edit the question.

Comment: FWIW, the upper limit on k in both formulas at the top of the Wikipedia article is not right: it is one too great. That is, in the first formula the upper limit on k should be n - 1, not n, and in the second formula the upper limit on k should be n, not n+1.

Answer (score 2):

You mean the two equations on the top of the page? You say you can prove the first by algebra - in that case, the second is just in terms of $n+1$ rather than $n$.  In other words, it's just the first formula shifted by 1 (for $n$).

It doesn't seem to have any major implications, just a preference; much like $d(x_{n-1},x_n)$ versus $d(x_n,x_{n+1})$

Comment: XD I get it now. Thanks a lot